# SD CARD saying read only after I tried to delete files from the card

Tags: macos, bug

I have a 1 GB SD card that I have been using with my zoom H4n recorder. I literally recorded onto the card, inserted it into my Mac OS x computer, pulled the recordings, and when I tried to delete the files, the card switched to read only. This has happened to two of the exact same 1 GB cards, and now I have no way of using them anymore. Does anybody know what the problem is, and how I can fix this? I appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't bump the "read only" switch on the SD card when you were handling them/inserting them into the laptop? I know I've done that myself.

Comment: Can you insert the card into another computer (or the recorder) and delete the content there?

Answer (score 1):

Are these cards NTFS formatted and have you only had this problem since updating to Mavericks?  Are you using the free NTFS-3G and/or MacFuse NTFS driver? If you answer yes to all, then that is the cause.  I'm having the same issue and may have to buy Paragon's NTFS driver.

Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling NTFS-3G and MacFuse